# Error E2223 $DENYPACKAGEUNIT 'System.Win.ComServ' cannot be put into a package, How to solve this?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have resolved unicode issues and at the end stuck with this error-

```
[dcc32 Error] E2223 $DENYPACKAGEUNIT 'System.Win.ComServ' cannot be put into a package
```

I cannot avoid `ComServ` from adding into the package but I need to get this build successfuly. The package is being build on `XE6` and original from `D2007` (Has same problem) I want this component installed.
Any quick solution to this problem?

I can clearly see in the OleAuto-

```
{$DENYPACKAGEUNIT}
{ OleAuto cannot be used in a package DLL.  To implement
  an OLE automation server in a package, use the new
  OLE automation support in comobj and comserv.
}
```

What does this mean and How should I implement above quoted suggestion?

Comment: The comment could be clearer, but it's really true that you mustn't use the ComServ unit in a package. Instead, use it in the main DLL project. All it does is implement the functions that any COM DLL needs to implement. Use ComObj in your package; it knows how to register itself with the ComServ class factory. I'm confused about how you got into this situation, though. It has nothing to do with Unicode, and the package restriction has been present forever. How did your code get into a package project in the first place? What task were you trying to accomplish at the outset?

Comment: {$DENYPACKAGEUNIT} OFF solves the problem

Comment: This last comment should be an answer